# Missing "move to SD" on HTC Desire 310

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, external-sd, insufficient-memory, app2sd

So, I bought this phone some time ago, an HTC Desire 310, which should have 4GB of internal memory, of which 2GB actually available to the user.

On the phone I also installed an 8GB SD card for picture and similar.

However, recently I keep getting "not enough space" when I try to update some of the bigger apps I have installed from Google Store, even if there are about 250 MB free.

I have tried cleanin the caches, so regaining some 50 MB, but still "insufficient space".

I also tried to move the apps to the SD card, but it would seem that the version of android here installed, some custom 4.2.2, **does not allow moving apps to SD**.

How can I then solve such a problem? Is there a way to restore the missing "move to SD" option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As phones with significant amounts of internal storage became prevalent, Android started to store application and user data on the same partition. As the latter was  traditionally stored on an SD card, these phones now call it an "internal SD" card, although no actual SD card is used. In this arrangement, it makes no sense to "move apps to the (internal) SD card", because it would still reside on the same internal partition, occupying the same space, so these  implementations of Android do not have this button. Sadly, they didn't feel the need to allow moving apps to the external SD, because they thought the internal storage couldn't reasonably be exhausted simply by installing apps - or that this option would confuse users. So, you can not move apps to the external storage. You can, however, move personal data (e.g. music, videos, pictures) to the external SD which will free up space to install apps on.

Also, if you have root on your phone, you could create an additional partition on your external SD card and move apps there using an application or script designed to do that - my favorite is Link2sd, you can look it up in the Play store.

Comment: All of my picture and music are already on the external sd card, so there is nothing I can move, it's all app data really...

Comment: Also, there are some apps that keep a ridiculous amount of cached data, for example the Facebook and 9gag apps. You could wipe data of these applications to regain space temporarily - although you will have to log in again to these apps. Other than this and jettisoning some apps you can't really do anything on an unrooted phone to help the issue.

Comment: Should the phone be rooted, what are the options?

Comment: You could then use [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD). You have to create a second partition on your SD card for this app. This app can then move other apps to this partition and leave links in their place which occupy next to no space. The other apps and the user will not notice any change. I'm sure there are other rooted solutions, but I never really bothered to look since this is what always worked for me and what I can recommend.